# Would implementing files (all types: audio, video, text, etc.) as database tables and their content as their rows be worthwile?

Tags: database, file

Consider I modify the way files are stored in a system, where every file name would actually be the table name in a database and each line in the file would actually be the rows of that table. **Would that increase overall system speed? would it be worthwhile? what are the tradeoffs?**

To further clarify the distinction between this and the normal use of a database, consider the files not to simply be text files, but also audio, video, binary, etc. where they are stored in the manner mentioned in the previous paragraph.

Immediate benefits that I can see from this is that i can read/write any line from/to a file without having to repeatedly read/write the previous lines until reaching the desired line. Another benefit would be simultaneous reading/writing of files.

**Please do not confuse this with a database file system, this is a file implementation**

Comment: what is the question here? " Would that increase overall system speed?" - faster than what?

Comment: Just modified it to make it clearer

Comment: What would the "lines" of a binary file be?

Comment: it could be any number of things, from simply text files to actual compiled programs

Comment: I didn't look at the implementation of how binary files are stored, but I'm sure I can derive something from there to know how to implement binary lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to your benefit of reading writing by location, the additional benefit are.

***Pros***

**Indexing**

Indexing the text with full text indexing that can give searching benefits. Ofcourse the size of database will probably be more then the conventional file sizes. But you have benefit in terms of performance because database system will have only one file handle open, and it will do caching and will improve performance and cause less fragmentation.

**Lock/Performance**

Opening/closing multiple files will put little more overhead in terms of performance because each open/close requires access control check and locking.

**Replication**

Replication benefits, if you put them in mysql, mysql replication is easy to setup and you can keep multiple backups easily.

**Maintanence**

Transfering, maintaining and querying database will be much easier then in terms of files.

***Cons***

**File Browser Access**

You can not access files through explorer or normal file system api, you will need some sort of access api probably REST based api or some viewer that can read the database.

You can check my [blog](http://akashkava.com/blog/127/huge-file-storage-in-database-instead-of-file-system/) about more detailed analysis.

Comment: File Browser Access: I assume that would be application specific, so it would be the responsibility of the application to know how to read from it if I provide an API (Video player, Text editor, etc.)

Comment: Yes, infact we also have 600GB of files and we store it in database, it becomes easier to setup replication, transfer, query and maintain, for small number of files database is costly but for huge number of files, it works well.

Comment: Please check my blog entry, in the last line of the edited answer, you will find more details.

Comment: Just read the entry, in relation to what you did I'm trying to do 2 more things 1) break down the blob even further to single lines. 2) make those blobs comprehensible so they could be read on their own

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some benefits on speed are present, but there's a lot of issue which make the cons overwhelm the pros.

- No easy way to support [Transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)
- No easy way to support typification of fields (think about a file with BLOB objects in it)
- Relationship constraint
- No trivial support for cache, accessing RAM is faster than accessing disk
- No easy way to support something like "ALTER TABLE"

I guess that if you write something which support all this kind of issues you've written a sql engine...